# Puppeteer - missing Unicode icons

Tags: puppeteer, chromium

I'm rendering a fragment of my page into a PNG using `html-to-image` and then downloading the result into a file using `puppeteer`. Everything works fine but when I run it in a docker container that's build upon alpine image, some Unicode icons are not rendered. For example - when text includes a "rocket" icon ( unicode code U+1F680) then in the result image is just a square.

[image: result image]

I tried to install some apk packages with font but it's still the same. Any idea?

Comment: Hi @Petr Skokan find any solution for these boxes